# In scratch "repeat until"

Tags: scratch

Using scratch "repeat until" will not exit when space bar is pressed unless the space bar is held down continually.  I am learning scratch.  Working with LEDs (low voltage lab stoplight).  I have them blinking in a sequence.  I press the space bar and the sequence pauses.  If I hold the space bar down for a couple seconds, the sequence will stop.

[image: Scratch Code Stop Light]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `repeat` condition is checked only after every loop, so you have to press it until the current loop is finished.

Alternatively, you can signal an event on keypress: `when space key pressed` `broadcast messageStop` and use this message to stop the loop.

If you want to stop immediately without finishing the loop do `when space key pressed` `stop all`